# How to control alignment of lessless in new line in clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

clang-format format the following code like this by default:

```
void func() {
  return some_func(some_variables)
         << "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
         << "asdaaasssssssss";
}
```

However, I wish clang-format may align `<<` to default indent width (8 spaces), like

```
void func() {
  return some_func(some_variables)
          << "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
          << "asdaaasssssssss";
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @atru clang-format: A tool to format C/C++/Java/JavaScript/Objective-C/Protobuf code.
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html

Comment: Why did this get so many downvotes? Seems a valid question to me.

Comment: @valiano thank you, I was pretty sure the OP was referring to clang compiler (and related confusions are not uncommon). Not the downvoter, some of the downvotes could come from a confusion like mine but no idea really because I don't use this tool and don't know the complexity of the question. Actually, I'm not sure but if I recall correctly the question stated "clang" instead of "clang-format" and there was no tag. I'm pretty sure - I wouldn't open it if the tag was there since I'm not familiar with the tool. So it was OPs original formulation that most likely lead to the downvotes.

Comment: @atru Sorry for the confusion. But I have used "clang-format" in the subject of the question, and also added "clang-format" as a tag. I quite understand this clang cannot do this, but clang-format can.

Sorry again if it also confuse somebody else.

Comment: @KaiZhang It's all good, I'll remove my comments, except for the last one because it may explain the downvotes. Hopefully you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clang-format `AlignOperands` option is relevant in this case. Here's its description from the [doc](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

> **AlignOperands (bool)**
>   If true, horizontally align operands of binary and ternary expressions.
>   Specifically, this aligns operands of a single expression that needs to be split over multiple lines.

The default value of the `AlignOperands` option is `false`. In your example, the result of clang-format is with `<<` aligned to `some_func`, as if `AlignOperands` is set to `true`:

```
void func() {
  return some_func(some_variables)
         << "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
         << "asdaaasssssssss";
}
```

If not set explicitly, this option may be set by some predefined styles, such as the LLVM style (`--style=llvm`).

For having `<<` indented according to the defined indent level, make sure `AlignOperands` is set to `false`.  For example, for `IndentWidth: 4`, the expected result would be:

```
void func() {
    return some_func(some_variables)
        << "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        << "asdaaasssssssss";
}
```

The exact alignment of the expected result, where line 2 is indented with 2 spaces, and lines 3 and 4 are indented with 8 spaces, cannot be achieved with the latest clang-format, AFAICT.